# Throw SOAP exception when there are pending Entity Framework database migrations for any SOAP request

Tags: entity-framework, wcf, exception, soap

I want to throw a SOAP exception when there are pending Entity Framework migrations and someone sends any SOAP request. If I throw a `FaultException` within my `Global.asax`, I get a html response from the IIS. This works but it is rather ugly. So I tried to throw it within the `IServiceBehavior.Validate()` method of my `ServiceBehavior` class.

```
 public void Validate(ServiceDescription serviceDescription, ServiceHostBase serviceHostBase)
 {
     var isDatabaseUpdateRequired = new MyDb().GetPendingMigrations().Any();
     if (isDatabaseUpdateRequired) throw new FaultException("There are pending migrations.");
 }
```

But I do not get any XML response with the error message on my SoapUI client. Where should I throw this exception?

Answer (score 1):

You can throw this exception in a class that implements the interface `IDispatchMessageInspector`. Implement `IDispatchMessageInspector` to inspect or modify inbound or outbound application messages either prior to dispatching a request message to an operation or before returning a reply message to a caller.

When the server receives the client request, the `DispatchMessageInspector` intercepts all the client requests.

[image]

The picture above is the implementation of `IDispatchMessageInspector`, Throw an exception in the `BeforeSendReply` method.

[image]

The client sends a request to the server and gets an exception message.

[Here is a link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.idispatchmessageinspector?view=netframework-4.8) about the `IDispatchMessageInspector` interface.